# Is express() function used in expressJS, a global function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is express() function used in the second statement a global function?.
Where can I find its declaration?. I could not find it in my project folder.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
```

Comment: It's not global - you import it into the local scope from the `express` package on line 1.

Comment: `express` function define in https://expressjs.com library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you are doing:

```
// creating a variable named express and storing return value of require function
// require is a nodejs function, in this case it is called with parameter called express which loads express module
var express = require('express');

// Executing the function stored in express variable
// And storing the result into app variable 
var app = express();
```

So, where does the express comes, you are declaring it in line 1. `var express = require('express')` is just a convention, you can use any valid variable name. Following would also work:

```
var expServer = require('express');
var app = expServer();
```

Comment: If two files want to require `express` and initialise an `app` variable, should they both call `express()`, or should just one call `express()` and expose that result as a global variable to be shared?

Comment: It should be imported into one file and then exported as a global variable and will be used in the <server>.js file where you will initialise the server with app.listen(<port>). As one express() instance will be used to configure the whole application, using another will result in two express configs and either one will overwrite the another or some of the configs defined in the files will not be present in the application.

Comment: What would you expose it as a global variable. A server has one entry point and that is the base and node calls it directly.  Yes you can expose and import into another module and call it there, in that case another instance of the server will be created.

Comment: Thanks @SnnSnn, was kind of tricky for me. So express.js exports a function, right?

Comment: No problem. Yes, these are open source projects, you can always check source code: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js

See it exports createApplication function as default. Default means you can name it anything when you import it.

Answer (score 0):

Express is a npm module and you need to import it in order to use it, jsut like other npm packages.

> Where can I find its declaration?. I could not find it in my project folder.

Its declaration is in the node_modules directory and you don't have to do anything with it.

Here is the example for using [express](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/index.htm) and creating a server from it.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.send("Hello world!");
});

app.listen(3000);
```